# calling executable from a background process and passing a parameter to it

Tags: c#, .net, process, executable, exe

I have an Console application which runs as background process and there is an exe which needs to be called.This exe takes complete fill path as parameter and then encrypts that file.
I did this way :

```
Process.Start( "myapp.exe" );
```

But what i want is this :

```
Process.Start( "myapp.exe file1.txt" ); // File1 is parameter of that exe
```

But this is not working.
Looking for help & advice.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like this:

> Process p = new Process();
>
> p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
>
> p.StartInfo.FileName = "myApp.exe";
>
> p.StartInfo.Arguments = "file1.txt";
>
> p.Start();

Comment: what do you mean by UseShellExecute=false ?

Comment: ShellExecute essentially says whether or not to use the operating system shell to execute the process. You typically use the shell when you want to start an application that is associated with a document. So if you "start" a .htm file it will in effect open up the default browser with the html file displaying it it. In your case you don't need this.

Answer (score 2):

**You want to use the `ProcessStartInfo` class.**

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.startinfo.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.aspx for an example on how to use this.

Use the `Arguments` property to set your arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Try `Process.Start("myapp.exe", "file1.txt");`

Comment: Not working isn't a very helpful statement. What didn't work? It works for me so it might be a problem with your application path or doc path.

Answer (score 1):

```
Process.Start("[drive]:\[directory]\myapp.exe", "file1.txt");
```

Substitute the actual drive and directory where indicated

Answer (score 0):

Process.Start(<`the nameof the process`>,<`the parameters`>)
In your case

```
Process.Start("myapp.exe","file1.txt")
```